# DAX Measure to Sum the value of the column

Tags: ssas, dax

I want to show the % of area expiring each year. i.e.Formula= % of (Expiring Area of that year/ Sum(Expiring area of all year or 5 years))

Suppose Expiring area for 2018 is 1000 and total of Expiring area (of 5 Years i.e. 2018-2022) is 11000 then % of Expiring area is % of (1000/11000) =9.09 %

similarly for 2019 Expiring area is 2000
so % of (2000/11000)= 18.18

I am getting difficulty in the calculating sum of 5 years Expiring Area which is the denominator part of this calculation. Please Help me on this.

I tried with this but it dosent work.

Calculate(SUMX('Lease Events', [Expiring Area]),dateadd('dates'[date],5,Year),All(tenant))

Comment: I got the answer this expression works CALCULATE([Expiring Area], ALLSELECTED('DATES'))

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have 5 years of data the denominator would just be:

```
SUM([Expiring Area])
```

Comment: I got the answer this expression works  CALCULATE([Expiring Area], ALLSELECTED('DATES'))

Comment: Excellent solution!